# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Groupld: warning: ignoring file FTFramworks/FacebookSDK/AccountKit.framework/AccountKit (2 slices)

Tags: xcode8

I'm not a developer just trying to get an app to run locally on my machine. Any help is appreciated.

> Ld
>   /Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FTApp.app/FTApp
>   normal x86_64
>           cd /Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam
>           export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
>           export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LGSideMenuController
>   -L/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks/Flurry -L/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks/GoogleAnalytics -F/Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks/MAPBox -F/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks/FacebookSDK -F/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks -F/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam/FTApp/FTFramworks/Crashlatics -F/Users/lukeheald/Desktop/FullTeam -filelist /Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Intermediates/FTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FTApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-aqvkqicetlajrubccnhlqhfazcfb/Build/Intermediates/FTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FTApp_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lLGSideMenuController -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/lukeheald/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTApp-

Comment: Can you provide a more clear question? What app are you trying to run, what are you doing, etc. You can try reading this article about how to ask a question to get useful answers as fast as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am trying to run an app I funded. It's an app for footballers. I am interested in running it on my local machine to play around with it as I recently started computer science. 

I have downloaded our source code, installed cocoapods and updated. I hit run to build the app and I get the error above.